# What happens to data sent by Handler, but not rendered in browser?

Tags: python, tornado

Let's say I have this handler:

```
class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        users = models.Users.objects()
        self.render(
            "index.html",
            page_title='My Webpage',
            page_heading='Welcome to my Page',
            users = users
        )
```

Users model could be:

```
class User(Document):
    firstName = StringField()
    lastName = StringField()
    title = StringField()
    email = StringField()
    phone = StringField()
    org = StringField()
```

And then in index.html:

```
{% extends "main.html" %}
{% autoescape None %}
{% block body %}
<h1>{{ page_heading }}</h1>

<h2>All the User's first names:</h2>
{% for user in users %}
    <p>{{ user.firstName }}</p>

{% end %}
{% end %}
```

What happens to the rest of the info in the Document for `users`? Does it get sent to the client anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, why should it be? The only thing sent to the client is the rendered HTML. If you do not include some data in that HTML, it doesn't get sent anywhere.